# Using jQuery in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, jquery-selectors

It is always recommended (for example see [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)) to put JS links in the footer. A typical example of PHP page will be

```
include 'header.php'
Page Content
include 'footer.php'
```

We add custom jQuery codes to the `Page Content` for a certain page, while loading the jQuery library at footer. This will cause problem, as jQuery library must be loaded before jQuery codes.

**QUESTION 1:** How do you put jQuery library in the footer, and put custom codes in each corresponding case?

One possible solution is to include all jQuery codes (for all the website pages) in the footer. In this case, all jQuery codes can be added to a JS file instead of inline JavaScript. This will be something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.div1').click ....
$('.div2').click ....
.....
$('.div99').click ....
```

**QUESTION 2:** Doesn't it slow down the JavaScript process, as in each page, JS must be listening to possible events for DOM elements which does not exist in the current page? For example, JS must look after 99 DIVs, while we have a few DIVs in each page.

Comment: _It is always recommended to put JS links in the footer._  Why is it so?

Comment: this is because if the script is too long, it won't make the page load slower, i.e. the page will load first and then the script to be executed

Comment: It is not always recommended to put JS in the footer.  This was the case at one point because it would then fire after the page has been loaded, but with the advent of onload event handlers this is not a necessity (and hasn't been for a very long time.)  Also, try only asking one question per post.  It helps us have clean answers to your questions.

Comment: I added a link for recommendation to put JS links in footer.

Comment: jquery min size is 96KB which wouldn't make any performance difference in your website comparing to the benefits you get from jquery library.

Comment: @thavan On slow connections, it makes difference for the visitor's experience (what he sees when loading the page).

Comment: Thanks Ali, that's a very useful article.  I've not run into any issues with this in the past, especially if you cache your scripts and  use AMD to load your scripts.  There are lots of ways around this issue.

Comment: @ThinkingSites this is not matter of having issue. I try to understand the conflict between recommendation and best performance.

Comment: @everyone the reason to place JS links at the bottom of the page isn't anything to do with the execution of the JS itself but rather due to the fact that a lot of browsers block concurrent download streams when it's loading JS files. Therefore, to avoid bottle necks, let the browser request all other assets before it requests the JS files. It's a download responsiveness issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 1**
Standard practice is to place large scripts in its own file and have the script tag in the header.  As long as you're calling $(document).ready you're not incurring any hits to performance as that script will only run when the document is loaded.

The intent of putting the JS in the footer was so that it would execute after the entire page has been loaded but this is no longer necessary with body onload events.

If you're really intent on leaving the JS in the footer, it's a fairly simple task to create a page variable with the script name you want to load, and pass that to your footer script.

**Answer to Question 2**
No, the page isn't slowed down.  If jquery doesn't find a matching tag, it does not bind any event.  Even if there were 99 divs on the page, it's not a performance hit, because the events are stored by reference, and only the invoked DOM item and its event will be fired.

Comment: Standard practice is *bad*, only the JS's that's absolutely required should be in the <head> and all the external JS files should be merged together and loaded as late as possible. JS parsing blocks the UI thread.

Comment: This is incorrect. The intent of putting JS in the footer is to optimize browser requests and download speeds.

Comment: and answer 2 is also incorrect. If you're asking jQuery to query the DOM looking for matches, it has to do that. And that takes time. Is it enough time to worry about? It all depends.

Comment: If it's in the footer, then $(document).ready won't be called. Try putting an alert in a script block above the jquery references (w/jquery loaded at the bottom of the page) - it won't fire and you''ll get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined message).    I fought with the stock implementation of MS's dotnetCore template which loads jQuery at the bottom of the page getting the error message above.
 
jQuery should go in the header, lest other parts fail to execute properly (document.ready won't fire - at least not in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You want to load JS as late as possible and preferably from one file - if you're using something like modernizer it will still need to go in the head.

As far as deferring jQuery goes @samsaffron wrote a pretty definitive post on it - http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax